# Need help getting started with Node and JS (learnyounode exercises)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just started using node (also just learning javascript) and I am trying to do the learnyounode exercises (hello world, baby steps) and I have no idea how to even start.

1. (I installed node), I created a folder called "nodeexercises"
2. For the first exercise "Write a program that prints the text "HELLO WORLD" to the console". I created in my node exercises folder I created a file: "server.js"
3. In that file I wrote the code below
4. Then I saved it and run node server.js

-

```
 var fs=require('fs');
 fs.writeFileSync("hello.js","Hello World file");
 var server=createServer(function(request,response){
    response.end("Hello World");
 });
 server.listen(3000);
 console.log("HELLO WORLD");
```

That wasn't right, however.

Comment: Which part wasn't right?    Did the program give you an error or is the program expecting a different answer?

https://github.com/nodeschool/discussions/issues/188

Comment: it says ReferenceError: createServer is not defined

Answer (score 1):

At that point, learnyounode is just showing you that node.js is acting like an interpreter.

Replace the code in your server.js file with:

```
console.log('Hello world!');
```

Then run like you did before.  It's not much of an application, but it does Hello, World!

Comment: If I change it to console.log('Hello world!'); it doesn't work as well-im getting this:
ReferenceError: createServer is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Julia/Desktop/Fullstack/FullstackTestFirst-Part3/nodeChallenges/server.js:3:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:456:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:415:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:407:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:575:10)
    at startup (node.js:160:18)
    at node.js:445:3

Comment: Edit: when I replace the code with just console.log('Hello world!'); and then run node helloWorld.js and then run learnyounode verify program.js I get:  Could not verify: No such file:

Comment: EDIT nevermind, I just realized Im an idiot haha and I run learnyounode verify program.js  instead of learnyounode verify helloWorld.js

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Web Development with Node and Express by Ethan Brown. It will get you a better understanding of how Node can be used for your own purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Most of your code is redundant, no offense. To do 'Hello, World' in any javascript variant, including nodejs, you simply have to type make a file like yournamehere.js and place the line `console.log("Hello, World!");` into it.

You can then navigate to the directory where the js file is and use the command `node yournamehere.js` and it should execute without a hitch. If it is not, something may be broken with your node.